# Linear equation with square root

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Linear equation in two variables must have the form $ax+by=c$. But can we see $\sqrt{x+y}=2$ as a linear equation because if we square both sides we get $x+y=4$ and both equations have the same solution set?

Comment: If $\sqrt{x+y}=2$, then $\sqrt{\alpha (x+ y)} =2 \sqrt{\alpha}$ (for some $\alpha>0$). So the equation in not linear. However, you can make a nonlinear transform (squaring) such that it becomes linear.

Comment: Yep, this works, unless the RHS is negative.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What RHS? $2$?

Comment: @anderstood Yep. Or $c$ if you prefer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given any function $f$, we can always take the linear equation

$$ax+by=c,$$

and apply $f$ to both sides:

$$f(ax+by)=f(c).$$

The resulting equation will generally not be linear unless $f$ is a linear function. Recall that a linear function is defined as satisfying the property

$$f(ax+by)=a f(x) + b f(y),$$

so in that case we get

$$a f(x) + b f(y)=f(c),$$

which is a linear function in the variables $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.

In your case $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, which is not a linear function, since it does not satisfy the property given above. Thus the equation obtained is not linear.

*Addendum:* Here I have used the common definition where a linear equation is an [algebraic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_equation) of degree 1 (and a quadratic equation is an algebraic equation of degree 2, and so on). Thus, even though the set of solutions to the equation $f(ax+by)=f(c)$ is a straight line, the equation is nonetheless nonlinear unless $f$ is a linear function. (See comments.)

Comment: I don't really agree with this answer. The question is not about the linearity of a function but the linearity of an equation. The solution set of the given equation is indeed a straight line, and there is no reason not to call it linear. Same would go with $(e^x)^a(e^y)^b=e^c$.

Comment: It depends on the definition of a "linear equation". The definition I am familiar with is that a linear equation is an *algebraic equation* of degree 1 (And a quadratic equation is an algebraic equation of degree 2, and so on). According to that definition, the equation $\sqrt{ax+by}=\sqrt{c}$ is not a linear equation, and neither is $(e^x)^a(e^y)^b=e^c$. If you weaken the definition to include any equation whose solution set is a straight line, then any equation of the form $f(ax+by)=f(c)$ is a linear equation even if $f$ is not linear (e.g. square root or exponent).

Comment: let's agree that the equation is quasilinear (or similinear) ;-)